# While deleting folder in Window OS it shows error : THE FOLDER IS DOESN’T EXIST

Tags: cmd, window, directory

For Example :
suppose I have a directory like "C:\Users\user\Downloads\Compressed\Developing Android Apps  Videos"

Now while deleting "Developing Android Apps  Videos" folder, If an error popped up with this message that "FOLDER DOESN'T EXIST", How to fix such issue ???

Comment: Please copy/paste the command you are using to delete the directory into your question. Do you have permission in that directory to delete?

Answer (score 1):

you have to follow this steps to solve this issue:

1. open cmd administration
2. enter command -> cd /d C:\Users\MK\Downloads\Compressed\Developing Android Apps  Videos
3. enter command -> dir /x
4. After the 3rd step, you can see some folder name and you need to use that name for 5th step.
5. enter command -> rmdir /q /s enter-folder-name

Hopefully, this could help you and please find an attachment for the exact process.
Thank you

[image: All 5 steps review]

Answer (score 0):

You can try below command also.

1.Open command prompt

2.Run below command

RD /S /Q pathOfTheFolder

ex: RD /S /Q C:\Users\Me\Documents\NewFolder

Here 
/S- Delete all sub folders and files. So once you delete any folder, all files and folders with in that folder will be deleted

/Q - Doesn't show Yes/No confirmation dialog box before deleting files are folders.